# What is the deserialize equivalent of ISerializable.GetObjectData?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm writing a custom serializer, and I've just finished implementing the portion for handling `ISerializable.GetObjectData`. But when I go to deserialize the information and re-apply it to the graph, I don't see an equivalent function for **Set**-ObjectData.

How do I go about re-applying `SerializationInfo` data to the graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement the special deserialization constructor as described in the MSDN Library documentation for [ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx):

> The ISerializable interface implies a constructor with the signature constructor (SerializationInfo information, StreamingContext context). At deserialization time, the current constructor is called only after the data in the SerializationInfo has been deserialized by the formatter. In general, this constructor should be protected if the class is not sealed.

For example:

```
protected Widget(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    // Perform your deserialization here...
    this.SerialNumber = (string)info.GetValue("SerialNumber", typeof(string));
}
```

Comment: Ah, `In general, this constructor should be protected if the class is not sealed.` That's the ticket. I was looking at `DataTable` and not seeing this constructor. Perfect, thanks.